# Managing object construction in Quarkus CDI

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I have a custom Logger that internally uses the jboss logger:

```
@Dependent
class LogImpl implements Log { //LogImpl & Log are custom

    @Inject
    Logger sink;   // this is jboss logger

...
}
```

I inject Log wherever it is required:

```
class MyService {

    @Inject
    Log log;
}
```

Calls to `log.debug(...)`, `log.info(...)` etc. on the log prints `LogImpl` as the logger name/category in the logs. What I need logged as the logger name/category is the name of the class where `@Log` is injected. In the example about, I need the logger name to be printed as `MyService` and not `LogImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Used a Producer to instantiate the custom log. `InjectionPoint` is used to get the class name of the object where `Log` in `@Inject`ed .

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class LogProducer {

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    Log createLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return new LogImpl(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

```
class LogImpl implements Log {

    private final Logger sink;

    public LogImpl(String name) {
        this.sink = Logger.getLogger(name); // Manual instantiation instead of @Inject. The producer calls this constructor with the correct log/category name.
    }
   ...
}
```